# What is a good library for interfacing with audio files?

Tags: c++, audio, file-format

I need a library for loading audio samples from a file and creating new audio files given the audio samples, author name, title, etc.

The 2 main audio file formats I'll be using are WAV and MP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org)